# gRPC Compute engine tutorial

Tags: google-compute-engine

I'm trying out GCE for grpc. In the past, I've set-up ECS (ec2 + NLB + ALB), but since I had weird behavior with the grpc server behind NLB, my team decided to try out GCE that seems to be better suited for GRPC.

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-compute-engine-docker#checking_required_services)

I need to determine the following

> To determine the ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME you can either:
> After deploying the Endpoints configuration, go to the Endpoints page
> in the Cloud Console. The list of possible ENDPOINTS_SERVICE_NAME are
> shown under the Service name column.

I'm at that point since I've just finished uploading with gcloud and enabled the required services.

There is no such "service" column, the closest thing I've got is this label

Service name: bookstore.endpoints.grpc-research.cloud.goog in the "Endpoints" section

I don't know if the documentation is out of date or I am at the wrong place or I'm missing something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Endpoints/Services/Service name]

The column is `Service name`. It is located in the Endpoints in the UI > Endpoints / Services / Service name. And it's the same you have shared in your post.

In my case is `function1.xxxxxxx.a.run.app`